# Excel 2021 | File Is in use | Locked for editing

Tags: microsoft-excel

Today i faced an error in my excel file.
Here is the error :
[image]
[image]
That user name is me.
I checked task manager for all open excel instances for close.
Nothing found.
I rebooted my pc. Problem is still there.
When i copy that file in new location it is working.
When i open file in notify mode and try to change and save it i faced this error :
[image]
What is going on and what is this error?
Please give me a solution to fix this.
**EDIT :**
My file has no pass at all.
In properties of that file read only option have not checked.

Comment: Admin please delete this question. I do n't have an option for delete. It is duplicate.

Comment: Dupe of their other question: https://superuser.com/questions/1726071/excel-2021-file-is-in-use-locked-for-editing

Comment: @SilverLight please do not create multiple accounts to ask duplicate questions around StackExchange. If you are blocked from a site, don't try to bypass the controls. And if bypassing controls, at least make sure the question is on-topic ...

Comment: Please go to that location you save this file, check if there are any temp files starting with $~, if yes, please delete it for a test.